# noVNC console on Openstack Dashboard is rendering garbled UI

Tags: python, openstack, libvirt, rhel7, novnc

I am running nova-compute on RHEL7. Openstack dashboard's noVNC console is rendering garbled UI for any instance having a UI console. Can somebody please help out? This is working just fine on RHEL65[image]

Comment: This question is not about programming, you should ask this question on [super user](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Is there any way to move this question directly to super user?

Comment: @Lafada I don't know, maybe the questioner need delete this question and ask on **super user** again.